# How to debug flask click command in pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I'm following [flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/database/#initialize-the-database-file). My code of `init-db` doesn't do what I'm expecting, and I want to debug it. But I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging in PyCharm is quite easy and similar to other IDE. 
You need just to add a breakpoint where you want to stop the code execution and then proceed line by line checking the variables.

Since there are no more information on what do you need, I suggest you to check [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) that from my point of view is very clear.

Answer (score -1):

In pycharm,you can find DEBUG button in Edit configuration.
[DEBUG button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDQM2.png)